# How to declare an interface method if i already have an implementation with generic

Tags: java, generics, interface

I want to make EventsRepository class to implement an Interface.
So it has some method:

```
public class EventsRepository implements IModelLayer {
 ...   
    public void getEvents(ICallback<EventBrite> resultEvents) {
        WebEventsDataSource.getInstance().getEvents(resultEvents);
    }
}
```

and this method has to implement some interface. On the basis of this method,
 what kind of interface method's semantic do i have to declare?
I tried to declare next interface:

```
public interface IModelLayer<T> {
    void getEvents(T resultEvents);
}
```

but it is not correct.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, you forgot the type, try with:

```
public class EventsRepository implements IModelLayer<ICallback<EventBrite>>{
    @Override
    public void getEvents(ICallback<EventBrite> resultEvents) {
            WebEventsDataSource.getInstance().getEvents(resultEvents);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The generic implementation and declaration would look like that:

```
public interface IModelLayer<T> {
    void getEvents(T resultEvents);
}
```

The interface is already right defined just the implementation of it needs to be changed.

Class implementation:

```
public class EventsRepository implements IModelLayer<ICallBack<EventBrite>> { //Generic type definition
...   
    @Override
    public void getEvents(ICallback<EventBrite> resultEvents) {
        WebEventsDataSource.getInstance().getEvents(resultEvents);
    }
}
```

For example in other cases:

```
public class StringRepository implements IModelLayer<ICallBack<String>> { //Generic type definition
...   
    @Override
    public void getEvents(ICallback<String> resultEvents) {
        //todo do something with the callback stuff.
    }
}
```

The thing here is you haven't defined the generic type you want to use. So you change `implements IModelLayer` to `implements ModelLayer<YourType>` and the method will use the type you defined.

Answer (score 1):

implements like below..this may help

```
      public class EventsRepository implements IModelLayer<ICallback<EventBrite>> {
        public void getEvents(ICallback<EventBrite> resultEvents) {
           WebEventsDataSource.getInstance().getEvents(resultEvents);
       }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `getEvents` parameter is always an `ICallback`, you can define the interface and class as follows:

```
public interface IModelLayer<T> {
    void getEvents(ICallback<T> resultEvents);
}

public class EventsRepository implements IModelLayer<EventBrite> {
 ...   
    public void getEvents(ICallback<EventBrite> resultEvents) {
        WebEventsDataSource.getInstance().getEvents(resultEvents);
    }
}
```

Of course, the definition of `WebEventsDataSource.getInstance().getEvents()` might also affect the answer.